# How to return cost, grad as tuple for scipy's fmin_cg function

Tags: python, scipy, fminsearch

How can I make scipy's `fmin_cg` use one function that returns `cost` and `gradient` as a tuple? The problem with having `f` for cost and `fprime` for gradient, is that I might have to perform an operation twice (very costly) by which the `grad` and `cost` is calculated. Also, sharing the variables between them could be troublesome.

In Matlab however, `fmin_cg` works with one function that returns cost and gradient as tuple. I don't see why scipy's `fmin_cg` cannot provide such convenience.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) with `jac=True`. If that's not an option for some reason, then you can look at [how it handles this situation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L49):

```
class MemoizeJac(object):
    """ Decorator that caches the value gradient of function each time it
    is called. """
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.jac = None
        self.x = None

    def __call__(self, x, *args):
        self.x = numpy.asarray(x).copy()
        fg = self.fun(x, *args)
        self.jac = fg[1]
        return fg[0]

    def derivative(self, x, *args):
        if self.jac is not None and numpy.alltrue(x == self.x):
            return self.jac
        else:
            self(x, *args)
            return self.jac
```

This class wraps a function that returns function value and gradient, keeping a one-element cache and checks that to see if it already knows its result. Usage:

```
fmemo = MemoizeJac(f, fprime)
xopt = fmin_cg(fmemo, x0, fmemo.derivative)
```

The strange thing about this code is that it assumes `f` is always called before `fprime` (but not every `f` call is followed by an `fprime` call). I'm not sure if `scipy.optimize` actually guarantees that, but the code can be easily adapted to not make that assumption, though. Robust version of the above (**untested**):

```
class MemoizeJac(object):
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.value, self.jac = None, None
        self.x = None

    def _compute(self, x, *args):
        self.x = numpy.asarray(x).copy()
        self.value, self.jac = self.fun(x, *args)

    def __call__(self, x, *args):
        if self.value is not None and numpy.alltrue(x == self.x):
            return self.value
        else:
            self._compute(x, *args)
            return self.value

    def derivative(self, x, *args):
        if self.jac is not None and numpy.alltrue(x == self.x):
            return self.jac
        else:
            self._compute(x, *args)
            return self.jac
```

Comment: +1 Nice way of caching the last call's return! It wouldn't be too hard to overcome that last potential limitation (`f` called before `fprime`), right?

Comment: @Jaime: no, just repeat the trick used in `derivative`. See updated answer.

Comment: Waw, this is such an amazing solution, I just tested my code with something like `minimize(fun =self._cost_grad, x0=initial_theta, method='Newton-CG', options = {'maxiter' :20, 'disp':True}, jac =True,args=(X, n_features, n_samples)) `, and I got awesome results. The parameter `fun` expects a function that returns (cost, grad) as tuple, and `method` can be simply changed to perform `l_bfgs`, `bfgs`, `cg` or any optimizer out there in scipy. Thanks a million! I'm surprised this answer isn't prevalent.

Comment: @IssamLaradji: well, the SciPy folks already solved the problem by the new `scipy.optimize.minimize` wrapper.