# fmin_cg function usage for minimizing neural network cost function

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, scipy, neural-network

I am trying to port some of my code from MatLab into Python and am running into problems with `scipy.optimize.fmin_cg` function - this is the code I have at the moment:

My cost function:

```
def nn_costfunction2(nn_params,*args):
    Theta1, Theta2 = reshapeTheta(nn_params)

    input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, lam = args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]   

    m = X.shape[0] #Length of vector
    X = np.hstack((np.ones([m,1]),X)) #Add in the bias unit

    layer1 = sigmoid(Theta1.dot(np.transpose(X))) #Calculate first layer
    layer1 = np.vstack((np.ones([1,layer1.shape[1]]),layer1)) #Add in bias unit
    layer2 = sigmoid(Theta2.dot(layer1))

    y_matrix = np.zeros([y.shape[0],layer2.shape[0]]) #Create a matrix where vector position of one corresponds to label
    for i in range(y.shape[0]):
        y_matrix[i,y[i]-1] = 1

    #Cost function
    J = (1/m)*np.sum(np.sum(-y_matrix.T.conj()*np.log(layer2),axis=0)-np.sum((1-y_matrix.T.conj())*np.log(1-layer2),axis=0))
    #Add in regularization
    J = J+(lam/(2*m))*np.sum(np.sum(Theta1[:,1:].conj()*Theta1[:,1:])+np.sum(Theta2[:,1:].conj()*Theta2[:,1:]))

    #Backpropagation with vectorization and regularization
    delta_3 = layer2 - y_matrix.T
    r2 = delta_3.T.dot(Theta2[:,1:])
    z_2 = Theta1.dot(X.T)
    delta_2 = r2*sigmoidGradient(z_2).T
    t1 = (lam/m)*Theta1[:,1:]
    t1 = np.hstack((np.zeros([t1.shape[0],1]),t1))
    t2 = (lam/m)*Theta2[:,1:]
    t2 = np.hstack((np.zeros([t2.shape[0],1]),t2))
    Theta1_grad = (1/m)*(delta_2.T.dot(X))+t1
    Theta2_grad = (1/m)*(delta_3.dot(layer1.T))+t2

    nn_params = np.hstack([Theta1_grad.flatten(),Theta2_grad.flatten()]) #Unroll parameters

    return nn_params
```

My call of the function:

```
args = (input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, lam)
fmin_cg(nn_costfunction2,nn_params, args=args,maxiter=50)
```

Gives the following error:

```
  File "C:\WinPython3\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 588, in approx_fprime
    grad[k] = (f(*((xk+d,)+args)) - f0) / d[k]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried various permutations in passing arguments to fmin_cg but this is the farthest I got. Running the cost function on its own does not throw any errors in this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input variable in cost function should be an 1D array. So your `Theta1` and `Theta2` in `J` have to be derived from `nn_params`. And you need to `return J` as well.

Comment: I accepted the solution as returning just `J` seems to not run into the same error. The problem then I have that my error does not minimize (as I am not returning `nn_params`). How do you return `nn_params` and not run in the problem that the fmin_cg expects you to return scalars only? In MatLab, you can output both your gradient and your cost.

Comment: @Matt, you need to initialize the nn_params before you call fmin_cg, then hopefully the optimization function will update the nn_params for you.

Comment: yes I do random initialization of `nn_params` by generating first `Theta1` and then `Theta2` and unrolling them into `nn_params`. At the moment, my `nn_costfunction2` returns only `J` is that a problem? When I try returning `nn_params`, I get an error that it is an unsupported operand for type tuple (i.e. when I return both `J` and `nn_params`).

Comment: In the end I used info from the following place to solve my [second issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431070/how-to-return-cost-grad-as-tuple-for-scipys-fmin-cg-function). My final function was `scipy.optimize.minimize` set as follows `res = minimize(nn_costfunction2, init_params, args=args, method='CG', options={'maxiter':50,'disp':True})` with `nn_costfunction2` set to return `J,grad`. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add epsilon argument in function call:

```
fmin_cg(nn_costfunction2,nn_params, args=args,epsilon,maxiter=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this issue is due to the fact you let nnCostFunction2 return cost and grad.

But the scipy.optimize.fmin_cg function will only take single cost output of nnCostFunction2.

So retain single J or cost output from nnCostFunction2 function.

this is my function which is working:

`scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(nnCostFunction, initial_rand_theta, backpropagate, \
            args=(hidden_s, input_s, num_labels, X, y, lamb), maxiter=1000, \
            disp=True, full_output=True)`